# Querying Foreign Key models in Django

Tags: python, django

In a Django blog application, I have models for Tags, Articles, and News. Both Articles and News have a ForeignKey to Tag, which is used to group articles with the same Tags together.

Tag Model

```py
# Tags
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Tag Name', max_length=100, unique=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField('Cover Photo', upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = RichTextField('Tag Description')
```

Article Model

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    # tag
    TAGS = (
        ('main', 'Main'),
        ('featured', 'Featured')
    )
    ARTICLE_STATUS = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published')
    )
    title = models.CharField('Article Title', max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    magazine = models.ForeignKey(Magazine, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    image = models.ImageField('Cover Image')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='+')
    article_feature = models.CharField('Article Feature', choices=TAGS, max_length=20)
    article_status = models.CharField('Article Status', choices=ARTICLE_STATUS, max_length=20, default='draft')
    body = RichTextField('Article Body', null=False, blank=False)
```

I need to write a view for each tag View and list all the articles attached to the tag. How do I that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write unique views for every tag but you could write one view that will be called for every tag.
You can read about DetailView and how you can use it in the docs.

Comment: You are welcome. Upvote and select as answer please.